# Triple-backtick code blocks don't get blockquoted correctly

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown, code, blockquote

Suppose I have a code block like this contrived pseudocode:

````
```
Here {
  is
}

my code
```
````

When I select the whole block including the backticks and then use try to blockquote it using the button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, the block collapses into this:

````
> ``` Here {   is }
> 
> my code ```
````

I expect blockquoting to preserve each line of code like this (and to make sure the triple backticks are on their own lines):

````
> ```
> Here {
>   is
> }
> 
> my code
> ```
````

Note that blockquotes work correctly with code blocks that use indenting instead of backticks:

```
>     Here {
>       is
>     }
>     
>     my code
```